# Dynamic creation of forks in Oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie

My use case is as follows:

I have a Java action which will output an integer parameter, say `count = 5`. Based on the value of `count`, I want to create those many forks. I am not able to figure out how to get this done. Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in oozie.

What are you trying to do? If you run pig, hive, scalding or some other M/R from your workflow you can configure parallelism there.